# I am executing the below SOQL to get list of all upload documents today from Content Document object but for some reason I am not getting all the docs

Tags: soql

Can you please guide me in this.

```
SELECT Id, Title, ContentSize, FileExtension, CreatedDate, CreatedById, createdby.name FROM ContentDocument where CreatedDate = TODAY
```

Also, this is working fine in other org and in this org, when I query the ID of content document in the query, I am able to fetch the result for that missing document.

I am a system admin with all relevant permissions

Thanks Reagds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out today that with the Spring 19' update there is a new setting in the "Setup -> Permission Sets -> (choose an existing or create a new one) -> App Permission -> Content -> Query All Files: Allows View All Data users to SOQL query all files in the org".

This is not enabled by default for the admin user but you can at least enable it in a Profile/Permissions Set.

Also, now documented in the [API Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm)

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

No, you probably don't have all relevant permissions. There's special "[Query All Files](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_files_query_all_files.htm&release=218&type=5)" permission. Create a permission set with it and assign to yourself.